# Restore View State with segue ios

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, state

I have setting like this:

First controller reads data and sets in Second Controller.
Second Controller has a button that executes push segue to Third Controller with a countdown. 
After countdown I want to go back from third controller to second that should still have data. Is there any way to achieve this?

Also I am using Storyboards.

I send data to Second Controller in prepare func. Second to Third controller change is connected directly to button in Storyboards.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destination as! QuestionViewController
    controller.questionIDs = sender as! [Int]

}
```

To come back from Third to Second controller I use this code from Third controller:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nobodyAnsweredSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: Show your code that are using to push the data between Controllers. And the code that you use to segue from third to second.

Comment: I added all code that I use in these transitions

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nobodyAnsweredSegue", sender: self)
```

To this:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: self.navigationController is nil

Comment: I should have ask how you have the storyboard configured.

Comment: I just added navigation on start and it works. Thanks